# I do not want by Bash script to stop if a Hive command fails

Tags: bash, hive, hiveql

I have a bash script sending a lot of HiveQL commands to hive. The problem is that I do not want it to stop if one of these commands fails. I tried the usual Bash command:

```
set +e
```

but it does not work (the script stops running if one of the Hive command fails). Do you know where is the problem ? An option in my hive config or something :-) ?

Thank you !

EDIT: I use the Hiveshell, doing something like this:

```
#Send my command to hive ...
hive -S -e "\"$MyCommand\""
#... but I want my script continue running if the command fails :-).
```

Comment: sending commands to Hive through JDBC invoking Beeline shell or something else? add that information to the question.

Comment: I use the Hiveshell, sorry :-)

Comment: Have you tried `hive -S -E "\"$MyCommand\"" || true`?

Comment: Yes, it says "unrecognized option: -E". It seems that Hive does not recognized this option. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Run the commands in a subshell `(hive -S -e "\"$MyCommand\"")`

Comment: Ok this works very well, thank you very much :-) !